# Mongodb Atlas with Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, mongodb-atlas

I am trying to connect Mongodb Atlas with Spring Boot. And i have Mongodb ATLAS URI Connection String.

```
mongodb://root:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-shard-00-00.rbcol.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.rbcol.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.rbcol.mongodb.net:27017/invoicefinancing?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-i1vx5v-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Set url to Spring Boot application.properties file like that

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://root:<PASSWORD>@cluster0-shard-00-00.rbcol.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01.rbcol.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02.rbcol.mongodb.net:27017/invoicefinancing?ssl=true&replicaSet=atlas-i1vx5v-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

When i run the project I got below error.

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:518) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:406) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:270) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:253) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:84) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:34) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:91) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:51) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:114) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_72]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1949) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:302) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.fatalSE(Handshaker.java:296) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1509) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:216) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:979) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:914) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1062) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:747) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:123) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:74) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:403) ~[mongodb-driver-core-3.6.4.jar:na]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:387) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:292) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:260) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:324) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:229) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:124) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1491) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.build(SunCertPathBuilder.java:141) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilder.engineBuild(SunCertPathBuilder.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at java.security.cert.CertPathBuilder.build(CertPathBuilder.java:280) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doBuild(PKIXValidator.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_72]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

How I can fix this? Thanks

Comment: Which version of java are you using? and are you trying to connect from behind the corporate proxy?

Comment: Did you find an answer to your question? I have exactly the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

As your error suggests either you do not have valid SSL cert or there is no cert at all installed. Have you tried connecting by removing `ssl=true` parameter from your connection string?

Comment: since this doesn't include a solution, you better write it as a comment under the question.

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score -1):

Update your JDK, Let’s Encrypt certificates should be available in version 8u101.